# Disable WiFi auto-connect on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu

I run Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I'd like to control when my computer connects to a WiFi network, even a known one. How can I do this? There seems to be no option for it that I can find via the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Open **Network Manager**, click on your WiFi connection, then click the *Settings* icon (next to where is says *Connected*). Uncheck the box that says "*Connect Automatically*".

Comment: Where is Network Manager ? I have something called "Network" with options for 
"Wired" "VPN" and "Network Proxy" but nothing like what you describe. To be clear, I run Ubuntu 18.04 which uses Gnome3 for its window manager.

Comment: OK. Open *Settings*, then *WiFi*. Do you see the correct options there? I run Mint and sometimes forget that this is one of the tools that's been changed greatly.

Comment: Ah, finally. Thanks! Though  I notice the setting is found in the options for each network. I guess if I connect to a new network that network will be added with a "Connect automatically" option already set by default. Do you know where the defaults come from?

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, I don't know where the defaults are stored. I search through `/etc/NetworkManager` and didn't see anything.